# Deterministic wallet audit ability

Tags: deterministic-wallets

Deterministic wallet described in BIP 32 has an auditing functionality by sharing the public parent key.

https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#hierarchical-deterministic-key-creation

But if I use the variant if the Hardened Keys the generation of the chain code depend also by the private parent key.
With this type of key the auditing functionalities fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the auditing functionality relies on the non-hardened derivation.